# Разрядность процессора и его тактовоя чатота?

Tags: железо, процессор

Всем привет, возник вопрос насчет процессоров, а точнее насчет данного слайда 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот в чем вопрос: разрядность процессора зависит от тактовой частоты?
Т.е я имею ввиду, что сама разрядность определенного процессора является вовлеченной - постоянной либо 32 либо 64 бита, но чем выше тактовая частота тем быстрее работает процессор - т.е разрядность отображает своего рода тактовую частоту как бы "привязываясь" к ней - т.е я хотел спросить может ли например 32 битный процессор работать с такой же частотой как и 64 битный? Я правильно понял?

Comment: тактовая частота никак не связана с разрядностью а итоговую скорость работы можно было бы рассматривать например как произведение тактовой частоты на разрядность. хотя это слишком грубое приближение. Скорость выполнения операций зависит от множества нюансов

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Вот в чем вопрос: разрядность процессора зависит от тактовой частоты?

нет, не зависит. разрядность - это схемотехническая особенность реализации. Некоторые процессоры могут переключаться  с одного режима в другой и быть "одновременно" и 16 и 32 и 64битными (обычные intel/amd x86 процессоры тому подтверждением).

> Т.е я имею ввиду, что сама разрядность определенного процессора является вовлеченной - постоянной либо 32 либо 64 бита, но чем выше тактовая частота тем быстрее работает процессор - т.е разрядность отображает своего рода тактовую частоту как бы "привязываясь" к ней - т.е я хотел спросить может ли например 32 битный процессор работать с такой же частотой как и 64 битный? Я правильно понял?

Частота и разрядность - перпендикулярные понятия. То есть, вполне могут быть процессоры, которые 64битные и работать на низкой (десятки герц) и 8 битные, работающие на гигагарцах.

Но если посмотреть на историю intel/amd процессоров, то с увеличением частоты увеличивается и разрядность. Но это просто погоня за производительностью.

P.S.  А на слайде о разрядности написано немного по странному. Современные процессоры поддерживают sse команды, которые позволяют по 512 бит за один подход обрабатывать. Но это не делает их 512 битными.